# Java Measurement Tool for java 1.5 or 1.6

Tags: java

http://jmt.tigris.org/

Does anyone know if any similar project like this exist or anyone compile jmt for java 1.5 or java 1.6. Now JMT have problems with generics, overrides becouse it is generated for java 1.4

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools that scan for code issues and quality. The top projects are:

1. PMD at http://pmd.sourceforge.net, this is my favorite
2. Checkstyle at http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net
3. Findbugs at http://findbugs.sourceforge.net

The tool Sonar at http://www.sonarsource.org combines these and provides a UI, although as a developer I have had more luck with running the tools individually and adjusting them to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

For that, a great entry point would be [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/), which is totally focused on code quality and metrics generation, with also a good spot on vizualisation of these metrics.